# why git clean -dfX don't delete lib files while it is in .gitignore?

Tags: git, static-libraries

i am sure *.lib is in .gitignore

```
cat .gitignore | grep lib
*.lib

$ ls lib
TLib.lib  TLib_d.lib


$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)


$ git clean -dfX

$ ls lib
TLib.lib  TLib_d.lib     // the issue is here...
```

why these .lib files are not deleted?

Comment: Are those `.lib` files tracked by Git? (Do they show up in `git ls-files`?) If they were added to the repo before being put in `.gitignore` (or were force-added afterwards), `clean` wouldn't remove them.

Comment: *.lib is configured in .gitignore, so .lib files are just ignored by git, -X option may delete such files, but it doesn't happen:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git stops searching files, once it encounters a directory not in the index.  But in the case above, we are telling git to search all files matching ignore pattern. So, it'd better go in to all directories and search files.

This will also match `git ls-files` behavior. Given:

```
$ tree
.
├── foo.o
└── lib
    ├── TLib_d.lib
    └── TLib.lib

1 directory, 3 files

$ cat .gitignore
*.lib
```

Run following commands.

```
$ git ls-files -o
foo.o
lib/TLib.lib
lib/TLib_d.lib

$ git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard
lib/TLib.lib
lib/TLib_d.lib

$ git clean -n
Would remove foo.o
Would not remove lib/

$ git clean -nd
Would remove foo.o
Would remove lib/

$ git clean -nX
```

The last command does not print any files.  But it would be nice if it did:

```
$ git clean -nX
Would not remove foo.o
Would not remove lib/
Would remove lib/TLib.lib
Would remove lib/TLib_d.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this behavior only if the directory has nothing tracked by git in it.

If it will always have nothing in it that is tracked by git and you want the directory to go add the directory to the `.gitignore` file.

If you want the directory to stay but its contents to go, then you'll need to add an empty file that is tracked by git in the directory. The usual choice for this is an empty `.gitignore` file.